# Turing-completeness of Minimalism and HPSG

Tags: syntax, computational-linguistics, minimalism, grammar-formalism

I read several times that HPSG and Minimalism are Turing-complete. Could someone explain (or tell me some references) why this is the case? And does this constitute a major problem since natural languages are widely considered mildly context-sensitive?

Comment: Addressing only the last question, if so then the machinery of these two theories is "too powerful", and you should choose a less powerful engine.

Comment: So is LFG. It’s not really a problem per se but the formalisms are cumbersome for some syntactic constructions.

Comment: @Atamiri Thank you for your reply! Would you have some resources/reading suggestions on that topic?

Comment: The only book on this topic I’m aware of is “Formal issues in LFG”. It summarises the contents of several unpublished technical reports written by Xerox PARC researchers.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll have a look.